# how to show elapsed time in set text?

Tags: java, android, textview

How to Set Text When Time Has Come?

I am creating birthday application which have give the following msg when time arrived.
Please Comment Bellow :)
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Support your question with some code.

Comment: help ? any code sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Alarm Manager`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/